# Assigning loop results into an array using Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops

I'm copying some code over into Python from MATLAB and realised certain parts don't transfer as easily. I want to write a loop in Python where the size of the array is increased with every iteration. I.e., assign a new variable to a different index of the array. For sake of example, consider the vector in MATLAB as `x = [1 2 3 4 5 6]`. The resulting loop would be:

```
x = [];
for j = 1:6
    x(j,1) = i;
end
```

Now, in Python I have

```
r_x = []
for i in range(1, 6):
    x = i
    r_x.append(x)
```

Surely there is a more efficient way to assign values to an array when iterating in Python? Why is it not possible to do `x[i,1] = i (error: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple) or r_x.append(x) = x (error: 'int' object has no attribute 'append')`?

Comment: What is `i` in the MATLAB code?

Comment: If you are coming from MATLAB, then you should be using `numpy`.  That would be `x = np.arange(1,7)`.  `numpy` was designed to provide a MATLAB experience in Python.  Also remember that in Python, things are numbered from 0, not from 1.

Comment: Different languages work differently.

Comment: In Python you can just do `x = list(range(1, 7))`

Comment: @Scott Hunter you don't say?

Comment: `r_x.append(x)` should work. You don't need `= x` after it.

Comment: Totally ignoring my question here guys. I'm asking how to increase the size of the array with each loop.

Comment: If `x` is a list, it can only be indexed with `x[i]`, where `i` is a number (less than `len(x)`).  A `numpy` array can indexed with `arr[i,1]` - if it is created with the right shape.  You can't "grow" either by simply assigning new values (that's what `dict` is for).  If you want to "grow" something in a loop, use `list append`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can't create list elements by assigning to an index. You grow it incrementally using the `append()` method.

```
r_x = []
for i in range(1, 7):
    r_x.append(i)
print(r_x)
```

Python ranges don't include the ending number, so if you want 1 to 6 you have to use `range(1, 7)`.

However, Python also has shortcuts. For example, list comprehensions:

```
r_x = [i for i in range(1, 7)]
```

Comment: You can create/grow a `list` by assigning an iterable to a index slice: `x = [1, 2, 3]`, `for i in range(0, 7, 2): x[i:i] = [i]`, if you really really want to. Btw: twice as fast as `insert` at position 0.

Comment: `l = []; l[3:3] = [3]` the result is `[3]`, not `[0, 0, 0, 3]` You can still only append at the end.

Comment: That's right, always appends after the last element. There would be no defined behavior to fill the empty elements since `lists` are not typed in python.

Comment: I admit that my answer was simplified. Slice assignment is not the same as assigning to an index, and it's more complicated than I felt necessary to mention.

Answer (score 0):

Your two errors are explained by basic Python list and int properties

Make a list:

```
In [31]: x = [1,2,3]
In [32]: x[1,0] = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [32] in <cell line: 1>
    x[1,0] = 4
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

When `1,0` is a tuple (same as `(1,0)`).  Lists do not allow such an index.  `numpy` arrays, do, but that's another story.

Lists can be indexed with a scalar, an integer, that's in the right range.  Too large a index, and you'll get a `list index out of range`.  Lists don't grow to accommodate the index.

```
In [33]: x[1]
Out[33]: 2
In [34]: x[1] = 4
In [35]: x
Out[35]: [1, 4, 3]
```

List append is relatively efficient.  The underlying data structure has "head room" that permits such growth.

```
In [36]: x.append(4)
In [37]: x
Out[37]: [1, 4, 3, 4]
```

Your second error must have been the result of assigning an int to the variable:

```
In [40]: y = 3
In [41]: y.append(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [41] in <cell line: 1>
    y.append(3)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Only a `list` class object has an `append` method.

The basic data structure in MATLAB is a 2d matrix.  It has a known `size`.  It's been years since I worked extensively in MATLAB, but at the time, we tried to avoid iterations, preferring to work with 'whole-matrix' approaches.  I don't recall being able to grow a matrix by simply indexing new values.  Even if we could, it wouldn't have been efficient.  In newer MATLAB, there's a lot of `jit` compiling, that lets you get away with a lot of things that would been inefficient earlier.  Still, I suspect there's a time penalty to such practices.

I wonder, for example, if this is faster:

```
x = zeros(6,1);
for j = 1:6
    x(j,1) = i;
end
```

Or better yet

```
x = [1:6].'
```

`numpy` arrays are closer to MATLAB matrices in character.  But there are enough differences to catch wayward MATLAB users off guard.